# mysql: how to create table schema from select statement having union of two extra large tables

Tags: mysql

I have two extra large tables having size of gigs. I want to create a table using select of these two tables. Something like this

```
CREATE TABLE ABC SELECT A.FIELD1, B.FIELD1, etc FROM A JOIN B WHERE A.FIELD1=-1;
```

This query will not return anything. I just wanted to create the schema. Considering the table sizes, is there any better way than the above query?

Comment: You are missing `AS` . I didn't understand what are you trying to do? You want the table to contain any data or just the structure of this query?

Comment: @sagi i just need to create structure

Comment: Your query is correct, did you try to execute it?

Comment: @Shaharyar : I wanted to know any better query than this to create just the schema out of two large tables which doesnt not have anything common.

Comment: There is no other way, it is the only way you can create **customized schema** from tables. `Create table Like` is another way but it creates schema for only one table without any customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the structure, but not the data, just use a `FALSE` condition :

```
CREATE TABLE ABC AS
SELECT A.FIELD1, B.FIELD1, etc
FROM A 
JOIN B ON(1 = 2)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I dont have anything common in both tables, so I dont have any ON condition. False where clause is a nice Idea.